# 'li' text not align as expected

Tags: html, css

CSS codes:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

li { 
    padding-left: 1em; 
    text-indent: -.7em;
}

li:before {
    content: "• ";
    color: #28B779; /* or whatever color you prefer */
    font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>English</li>
</ul>
```

How I can make the text align as my bullet? Currently I got this:

[image]

Comment: Add `vertical-align: middle` to the pseudo element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Posting my comment as an answer..</sup>

Just add `vertical-align: middle` to the pseudo element.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -.7em;
}
li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #28B779;
  /* or whatever color you prefer */
  font-size: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>English</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

To align them perfectly, you need to style both the text and the pseudo-element with `vertical-align: middle`. Since CSS selectors can't select text, you will need to wrap it in an additional element:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -.7em;
}
li:before {
  content: "• ";
  color: #28B779;
  font-size: 2em;
}
li:before, li > span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>English</span></li>
</ul>
```